# Left join with Sum Clause with more than 1 table gives incorrect Sum

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the Sum of rows while applying a left join with more than 1 table. It seems it is creating a matrix of result which results in wrong sum function.

Example:

First Table: **Customer**

Second Table: **TotalAssets**

Third Table:  **TotalLiability**

Table Structure:

**Customer**

```
CustID(int) CustomerName(varchar)
1           Abc
2           Def
3           Ghi
```

**TotalAssets**

```
CustID      Amount
1           2000
1           1000
2           600
```

**TotalLiability**

```
CustID      Amount
1           1000
1           1000
2            800
```

Output Expected

```
CustID    TotalAssets TotalLiability
1         3000           2000
2          600            800
```

**Current Query**

```
 Select c.CustID , Sum(a.Amount) , Sum(l.Amount) From Customer c
 left join TotalAssests a on a.CustID = c.CustID
 left join TotalLiability l on l.CustID = c.CustID
 Group by c.CustID
```

The problem with this current query is the sum is not correct as i think the first left join create a first set with multiple records and then second one is applied.

Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

I find some luck by following method but it seems a bad/hacky option as in my case i have over 7-8 elements in group by and adding more left clauses results in query difficult to manage.

**New Query which is resulting correct result but looks very bad to maintains**

```
 Select Set1.CustID , Set1.TotalAssets, Sum(l.Amount) from (Select c.CustID , Sum(a.Amount) as TotalAssets From  Customer c
 left join TotalAssests a on a.CustID = c.CustID
 Group by c.CustID)Set1
 left join TotalLiability l on l.CustID = Set1.CustID.
 Group by Set1.CustID , Set1.TotalAssets
```

Comment: What is unexpected result?

Comment: And what is the result you get? Don't make us figure out your table structure and create our own test data.

Comment: @artm I had rewrite my question with sample output and short query with sample data.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I had updated my question with table structure, sample data current output and desired output.

Comment: there's comma `Sum(a,Amount)` - can this be a problem? change it to `Sum(a.Amount)`

Comment: @are I have update the code,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this gets you what you want with minimum complexity:

```
select c.CustId, isnull(a.Amount, 0) as TotalAssets, isnull(l.Amount, 0) as TotalLiability
from Customers c
left join (
    select CustId, sum(Amount) as Amount from TotalAssets group by CustId
) a on a.CustId = c.CustId
left join (
    select CustId, sum(Amount) as Amount from TotalLiability group by CustId
) l on l.CustId = c.CustId
```

You need to group/sum the two tables separately, since the data in them is independent. Left-joining both to the customers table ensures that customers with no entries in either/both tables are still reported.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select c.CustID 
, (select sum(a.amount) from TotalAssests a where a.CustId = c.CustID) as SumAsset
, (select Sum(l.Amount) TotalLiability l where l.CustID = c.CustID) as SumLiability
From Customer c
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries aren't the most performant, but it should work, and it is simpler to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

Hope the below works with less maintenance,

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (CustID int, CustomerName varchar(50)) DECLARE @TotalAssets TABLE (CustID int, Amount INT) DECLARE @TotalLiability TABLE (CustID int, Amount INT)
INSERT INTO @Customer
SELECT 1,
       'ABC'
UNION
SELECT 2,
       'DEF'
UNION
SELECT 3,
       'GHI'

 --Select * From @Customer

INSERT INTO @TotalAssets
SELECT 1,
       2000
UNION
SELECT 1,
       1000
UNION
SELECT 2,
       600 

--Select * From @TotalAssets

INSERT INTO @TotalLiability
SELECT 1,
       1000
UNION
SELECT 1,
       1000
UNION
SELECT 2,
       800 

--Select * From @TotalLiability

SELECT *
FROM @Customer
SELECT C.CustID,
       C.CustomerName,
       Sum(A.Amount) TotalAssets,
       Sum(L.Amount) TotalLiability
FROM @Customer C
JOIN @TotalAssets A ON C.CustID = A.CustID
JOIN @TotalLiability L ON C.CustId = L.CustID
GROUP BY C.CustID,
         C.CustomerName
```

Comment: `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` is giving you incorrect test data. Also, I don't think this would give the correct results anyway - does the output match the OP's required output when you test it?

Comment: It only "works" because your test data is wrong. Do a `select * from @TotalLiability` - notice that the duplicate rows were not inserted? That's because your `union` should be `union all`.

Comment: Tested: when I fix the `union` thing, I do get the wrong output.

Comment: Not sure what am I missing. but the output is,                                     CustID      CustomerName                             TotalAssets TotalLiability
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- --------------  --------------
1           ABC                                                              3000        2000
2           DEF                                                                 600         800

Comment: You are missing the correct test data: read my above comments. Look at your @tables after you fill them. The data does not match OP's.